# get logged user with NodeJS and Angular

Tags: node.js, angular

I have some users in my app, now I want to get one user at a time when they login.

this is my node.js

```
router.get('/currentUser', (req, res) => {
  User.findOne().then(user => {
    console.log(user);
    if (user) {
      return res.status(200).json(user);
    } else {
      return res.status(404).json({
        message: 'User not found'
      });
    }
  });
});
```

and on my angular app I have

```
getCurrentUser(user: any) {
console.log(user);
 return this.http.get(this.urlEnvironment + this.OneUserUrl).subscribe(data =>{
console.log(data)
});
}
```

the problem is it gets first user only from the database instead of the current user.

I have tried `find()` but it gets all those users.

Comment: User.findOne(). always return first element you need to pass argument e.g:    User.findOne({_id:id})

Comment: Ok but I want to get user info as soon login to the app? and can you explain what is that id? do I need to fetch from the params?

Comment: You can but best approach is using JWT or any type of token, First of all when you are in login in,  server side generate a JWT token to you, and then you catch the token response and save it on your local storage or cache, after each time when you doing any HTTP call anything on your server you add those in HTTP header , server catch your header and decode who are you, and get all of your data respectively by your token.

Comment: How do you log the user in? Is there a session? You need to pass the `_id` associated with that session in the `findOne()`.